# Is it possible to convert a keyword driven framework using Selenium WebDriver to Selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have developed a selenium keyword driven framework. It uses selenium WebDriver. Now I need to migrate to selenium grid. Can it done?
I used Java as the programming language.

Comment: Yes you can integrate selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Grid just provide browsers to run your tests which were written using Selenium WebDriver. Refer to Grid [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2):

> Grid allows you to :
>
> - scale by distributing tests on several machines (parallel execution)
> - manage multiple environments from a central point, making it easy       to run the tests against a vast combination of browsers / OS.
> - minimize the maintenance time for the grid by allowing you to       implement custom hooks to leverage virtual infrastructure for
>     instance.